# Angular: Control group of checkboxes with ngModel

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngmodel

I have a group of checkboxes with one parent, and then a number of suboptions

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" 
        id="{{ typeOptions.name | lowercase }}-{{ ALL | lowercase }}" 
        name="{{ typeOptions.name }}" 
        value="{{ ALL }}" 
        [(ngModel)]="typeOptions.selected"
        (ngModelChange)="setGroupSelected(typeOptions.name, typeOptions.selected)" />
    <label for="type-all">(Select All)</label>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let subOption of typeOptions.subOptions; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox"
        id="{{ typeOptions.name | lowercase }}-{{ typeOptions.subOptions[i].name | lowercase }}" 
        name="{{ typeOptions.name }}"
        value="{{ typeOptions.subOptions[i].name }}"
        [(ngModel)]="typeOptions.subOptions[i].selected"
        (ngModelChange)="toggleSelected(typeOptions.name, typeOptions.subOptions[i].name,
         typeOptions.subOptions[i].selected)">
    <label for="type-{{ typeOptions.subOptions[i].name | lowercase }}">
        {{ typeOptions.subOptions[i].name }}
    </label>
</div>
```

The whole group is bound to an Option interface

```
export interface Option {
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
  enabled: boolean;
  subOptions?: Option[];
}
```

The group is instantiated in the class RecipeSelectionComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges

```
typeOptions: Option = {
    name: 'Type',
    selected: true,
    enabled: true,
    subOptions: []
};
```

The function setGroupSelected is meant to set all the suboptions.selected to the same value as the parent, and toggleSelected is meant to loop through all the suboptions and set the parent to selected or not depending on if all the suboptions are selected or not.

The issues I'm having are twofold. I'm trying to deselect certain suboptions based on the query string. I'm able to set the selected to false for the correct suboptions but it doesn't change whether any of the checkboxes on the form is checked or not, suboption or parent. The other issue is that when I deselect a suboption through the form it simply deselects All the checkboxes in the group, not just the suboption
Does anyone know what I'm missing and how I can fix these 2 issues?

(Note: variable ALL is simply the string "all")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "name" of the "subOptions", you have written `name="{{ typeOptions.name }}"`, should be some like `name="{{ subOption.name }}"`. Futhermore, you use "value" in your suboptions. You should **remove** it

To simply the functions you can pass to your function "setGroupSelected" the typeOption itself

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  id="{{ typeOptions.name | lowercase }}-{{ ALL | lowercase }}"
  name="{{ typeOptions.name }}"
  value="{{ ALL }}"
  [ngModel]="typeOptions.selected"
  (ngModelChange)="
    typeOptions.selected = $event; setGroupSelected(typeOptions, $event)
  "
/>
<label for="type-all">(Select All)</label>
```

And your function

```
  setGroupSelected(option: Option, value: boolean) {
    if (option.subOptions) 
        option.subOptions.forEach((x) => x.selected = value);
  }
```

Idem, the inner options pass also the typeOption

```
<div *ngFor="let subOption of typeOptions.subOptions; let i = index">
  <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="{{ typeOptions.name | lowercase }}-{{ subOption.name | lowercase }}"
      name="{{ subOption.name }}"
      [ngModel]="subOption.selected"
      (ngModelChange)="subOption.selected = $event; toggleSelected(typeOptions)"
    />{{ subOption.name }}
  </label>
</div>
```

your function

```
  toggleSelected(option:Option)
  {
      if (option.subOptions.find(x=>x.selected)==null)
           option.selected=false;

      if (option.subOptions.find(x=>!x.selected)==null)
           option.selected=true;
  }
```

NOTE: It's a personal preference, but if I use (ngModelChange), I like  split the [(ngModel)] in `[ngModel]="variable" (ngModelChange)="variable=$event;anotherFunction(..)"`

Comment: I was under the impression that using ngModel and ngModelChange meant you didn't need to reference the $event. That they would be bound to the assigned object and event handling wouldn't be necessary

What about the other issue I'm having where updating the selected state in the Option or suboption doesn't update the checkbox in the form?

Comment: @Darkreaper, if you use "banana syntax" `[(ngModel)]` you needn't use $event, if you split in [ngModel], (ngModelChange), [ngModel] only binding from variable in .ts to the input, and (ngModelChange) is executed when the input change -but not make nothing more- I feel that the code I wrote should update the checkbox property. Sorry my bad! there was some errors in code. Just corrected. See a [stackBlizt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ylmusk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Awesomes. That's fixed the first issue of all the group's checkboxes unchecking when I toggle one of the suboptions. Still having an issue though with the form checkbox not unchecking even though I've set subOption.selected to false. Any ideas on that?

Comment: In the stackblitz looks like work well. See that I wrote in ngOnInit:`this.toggleSelected(this.typeOptions)` to give value to the typeOptions based in what are selected in "SubOptions". But you can choose write in ngOnInit:`this.setGroupSelected(this.typeOptions, this.typeOptions.value)` if you want that if typeOption.selected have priority over the subOptions. NOTE: As I "hardcode" the typeOptions I use ngOnInit, if you has a component that received in `@Input` the options you should call the functions in the "setter" of the input, if you received the values from API, call after get values